# why displaying html tag in view in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am developing asp.net mvc 5 and I saved data with special style in the database sqlserver but when I want to show at the view I encounter a problem that shows datas with html tag in the view .please help me to solve this problem

Action To save Data :

```
 [ValidateInput(false)]
            [HttpPost]
            [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
            public ActionResult InsertAboutConfirm(aboutu a, HttpPostedFileBase img)
            {
                if (img != null)
                {
                    Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
                    img.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" +g.ToString()+ img.FileName));
                    a.img = g.ToString()  + img.FileName;
                }
                db._AboutusRepository.InsertItem(a);
                TempData["result"] = "اطلاعات شما بدرستی ثبت شد";
                return RedirectToAction("InsertAbout");
            }
```

View:

@model Azmayeshgah.Models.aboutu

```
  <div class="container padding-top">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <!-- Widget Text-->
                        <div class="panel-box">
                            <div class="titles">
                                <h4>درباره ما</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12" style=" font-family:'B Nazanin'">
                               @if (Model != null)
                               {
```

@Model.matn

```
                               }

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Widget Text-->
                    </div>

                    <!-- Sidebars -->
                    <aside class="col-md-4">
                        <aside>
                            @*<h4>نوار کناری جستجو</h4>
                            <form class="search" action="#" method="Post">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="جستجو ..." name="email" type="email" required="required">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="subscribe">برو!</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </form>*@
                        </aside>

                        <!-- Widget Categories-->
                        <div class="panel-box">
                            <div class="titles">
                                <h4>تصویر</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                                    @if (Model != null)
                                    {
                                        <img src="~/images/@Model.img" alt="Alternate Text" width="300" height="250" />
                                    }

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Widget Categories-->
                        <!-- Widget Text-->
                        @*<div class="panel-box">
                            <div class="titles">
                                <h4>ابزارک متن</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p>لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>*@
                        <!-- End Widget Text-->
                    </aside>
                    <!-- End Sidebars -->

                </div>
            </div>
```

Output in the View:

```
<h2 style="font-style:italic;"><strong>sddvsdsdvsd</strong></h2> <p><strong>gsgsdsd</strong></p
```

[See Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6S3a.png)

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Model.matn)`

Comment: Stephen Muecke Thank You so Much